# Memory Based Full Text Search

Tags: c#, search, full-text-search

I have a social feature with a structure similar to a blog: posts and comments.

Posts have a field called body, and so do comments. The posts and comments are stored in a SharePoint list, so direct SQL Full Text Queries are out.

If someone types in "outage restoration efficiency in November", I really have no clue as to how I would properly return a list of posts based on the content of the posts and its attached comments.

The good news is, there will never be more than 50-100 posts I need to search through at a time. Knowing that, the easiest way to solve this would be for me to load the posts and comments into memory and search through them via a loop.

Ideally something like this would be the fastest solution:

```
class Post
{
    public int Id;
    public string Body;
    public List<Comment> comments;
}
class Comment
{
    public int Id;
    public int ParentCommentId;
    public int PostId;
    public string Body;
}
public List<Post> allPosts;
public List<Comment> allComments;

public List<Post> postsToInclude (string SearchText)
{
    var returnList = new List<Post>();
    foreach(Post post in allPosts)
    {
        //check post.Body with bool isThisAMatch(SearchText, post.Body)
        //if post.Body is a good fit, returnList.add(post);
    }
    foreach(Comment comment in allComments)
    {
        //check post.Body with bool isThisAMatch(SearchText, comment.Body)
        //if comment.Body is a good fit, returnList.add(post where post.Id == comment.PostId);
    }
}

public bool isThisAMatch(string SearchText, string TextToSearch)
{
    //return yes or no if TextToSearch is a good match to SearchText
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is not a trivial subject. As a machine does not have a concept of "content", it is inherently difficult to retrieve articles that are *about* a certain topic. To make an educated guess if each article is relevant to your search term(s), you have to use some proxy algorithms, e.g. [TF-IDF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tf%E2%80%93idf).

Instead of implementing that yourself, I'd advise to use existing Information Retrieval Libraries. There are a few really popular out there. Based on my own experience, I'd suggest to have a closer look at [Apache Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org). A look at their [reference list](http://wiki.apache.org/lucene-java/PoweredBy) shows their significance.

If you have never had anything to do with information retrieval, I promise a very steep learning curve. To ease into the whole area, I suggest you use [Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/index.html) first. It runs pretty much "out of the box" and gives you a nice idea of what is possible. I had a breakthrough when I started to really look at the available filters and each step of the algorithm. After that I had a better understanding of what to change to get better results. Depending on the format of your content, the system might require serious tweaking.

I have spent a LOT of time with Lucene, Solr and some alternatives in my job. The results I got in the end where acceptable, but it was a difficult process. It took a lot of theory, testing and prototyping to get there.

Comment: It'll be tough to have any third party API's added due to policy. Since I don't need to do any indexing necessarily, is there any other way? Thanks for your help :)

Comment: TF-IDF seems to be a process for data mining keywords from a document. It may or may not be the right fit here.

Comment: I can tell you from experience that a content-based search is very complex. You will not be able to recreate something others spent years on developing.
TF-IDF gives you an idea of how relevant a word in your search term is. In your example "in" is a lot less important than "restoration". By comparing frequency analyses of each record (TF) and all the records (IDF), "a lot less important" is converted into a numeric value that is used for sorting by relevance.

Answer (score -1):

Note: I have no experience doing this, but this is the way I would approach the problem.

Firstly, I would do your search in parallel.  By doing this, it will greatly increase the performance of your searching function.

Secondly, because you are able to input multiple words, I would create a scoring system that scores comment based on the query.  For example if the comments have 2 of the query words, it has a higher score value than a comment that only contains 1 of the query words.  Or, if it the comment contains an exact match, maybe it might receive a really high score.

Anyway, once all of the comments are scored based on the query input in a parallel loop, show the user the top comments as their results.  Additionally note, that this works because of the small data set sizes, 50-100.

Comment: I can promise you that it is not that easy. You have to take so many different aspects into account that you are better off using existing systems.